# Iphone Simulator as provisioning profile device

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-developer

I am trying to publish an ios app but xcode requires me a device registered in my account. I have to have a provisioning profile with a device registered. The thing is, i don't have a real ios device. Can i register a ios simulator as a device?

Comment: No. You need to register at least one real device.